# Comparing either values or index of two arrays in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, if-statement

I have two arrays with exact same values and index

```
const colors = ["#da9f64", "#f67dd1", "red", "gray"];
const colorsff = ["#da9f64", "#f67dd1", "red", "gray"];
```

I want to create a function that will do something particular IF either values or index of arrays match

something like this

```
function colorsMatch(){
if(colors.indexof() === colorsff.indexof()){
   someHtmlElement.classList.remove('d-none')
}
}
```

I tried everything  i was able to look up

Comment: I don't understand what the desired result is. Could you add some clarity and maybe an example of how it would be used?

Answer (score -1):

If your goal is to execute an action if all elements of two arrays match up, and you're sure they have the same length, you could do something like this.

```js
const colors = ["#da9f64", "#f67dd1", "red", "gray"];
const colorsff = ["#da9f64", "#f67dd1", "red", "gray"];
const colors00 = ["#da9f64", "#f67dd1", "red", "err"];

function colorsMatch(array1, array2) {
  const allMatch = array1.every((value, index) => {
    return array2[index] === value;
  });
  if (allMatch) {
    console.log("Do something");
  } else {
    console.log("Dont do anything");
  }
}

console.log("Matching original matching input");
colorsMatch(colors, colorsff);

console.log("Matching err input");
colorsMatch(colors, colors00);
```

Answer (score -3):

You'll need a loop of some kind:

```
colors.forEach((color, i) => {
  if (colorsff[i] === color) {
    // do something
})
```